# Boolean value not being set upon onClickListener

Tags: java, android, textview, onclicklistener

I have two classes. I am trying to change a boolean value depending on if the user clicks a checkbox. Then, depending on whether that value is true/false (whether the checkbox was checked or not), I want to display specific text in a textview. Here is the MainActivity class:

```
public class BoiseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

CheckBox cb;
public boolean isTrue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boise);

    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.boiseCheckBox);

    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isTrue = true;
        }
    });

public boolean isTrue() {
    if (isTrue == true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the new Activity that is opened once the user presses the "submit" button:

```
public class BoiseResults extends BoiseActivity {

TextView TV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boise_results);

    TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

if (isTrue() == true) {
        TV.setText("checkbox checked");
    }
}
```

The boolean value is never changed in the BoiseActivity class onCreate-> onClick method. Can anyone see what is wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the difference between classes and instances?

Comment: I do... should I create an instance of the BoiseActivity class in the BoiseResults class? I was thinking this would not enable me to access the values that were changed in the previous activity...

Comment: Look into some tutorials about passing data between activities and java itself. What's with `isTrue == true`?

Comment: I'm trying to check whether the variable has been changed (i.e. if someone has checked the checkbox).

Comment: What @immibis is saying: the instance on which `isTrue()` is called, and where `isTrue` is set are separate. You see `false` because `isTrue` is never initialized in `BoiseResults`, and being a primitive boolean, holds false by default.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to stop what you are doing and go grab a good OOP/Java Programming book, other way you will stumble with problems in every single step...

Comment: Even if BoiseResults inherits from BoiseActivity, it's a completely different istance of BoiseAcivity so isTrue will always be false. At the beginning I thought of a mistake but then the isTrue method showed that you may need a good java programming book :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what has been said on you picking up a book on OOP (come on guys, everybody started somewhere):
The `isTrue` instance variable of your `BoiseActivity` will be present in it's child class `BoiseResults` because it (`BoiseResults`) inherits `isTrue` from `BoiseActivity`, but it's value will not be set and therefore interpreted als false, as Vikram pointed out.

What to do to straighten this out:

- use `onCheckedChangeListener` for `CheckBox`
- pass the boolean ('if the checkbox has been ticked') to your second `Activity` via the `Intent` you are starting it with, links on how to do this have been given in comments
- ask yourself if `BoiseResults` really needs to subclass `BoiseActivity` (I do not think it does, it is just another `Activity`)
- get rid of all the boolean mayhem you created with the `isTrue()` method returning the value of your `isTrue` variable
- Rename `BoiseResults` to `BoiseResultsActivity` for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Your onCreate{...} method for BoiseActivity doesn't seem to be a closed method.

You don't need the isTrue() method as it is really only returning the value of isTrue and isTrue is already a public instance variable.  Regardless of that detail, you should look into (Explicit) Intents for passing data between activities: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider the use of the `OnCheckedChangeListener`;

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // DO SOMETHING HERE WHEN CHECKED/UNCHECKED
        }
});
```

You can then check whether it is checked or not using the `checkBox.isChecked()` method.

It's also best for you to avoid performing unnecessary checks on a boolean value like;

```
public boolean isTrue() {
  if (isTrue == true) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The following would achieve the same;

```
public boolean isTrue(){
   return isTrue;
}
```

With regards to your `BoiseResults` Activity, take a look at Intents if you are going to be changing from the BoiseActivity Activity to the BoiseResults Activity from your submit and need to pass data to BoiseResults.